# nginx location regex with curly braces and quotes doesn't work

Tags: regex, nginx

I have a site, running on nginx. I need to rewrite URLs like this one:

```
domain.com/blabla/88-aaa-aaaaa-aaaa/qqqq-qqq11-2qq-qqq.html
```

to this

```
domain.com/blabla/aaa-aaaaa-aaaa/qqqq-qqq11-2qq-qqq
```

it means - remove the number after slash, followed by a dash, and then the ".html" extension.

To achieve that, i tried to use

```
location ~* \/[0-9]{1,4}(-.*)(\.html)$ {
   ......
}
```

but in the location tester, it completely ignores the dash, and matches `.../88aaa...` , which I want to avoid. Then I read, that if the expression contains curly braces, single or double quotes must be used around the expression. So i tried this

```
location ~* "\/[0-9]{1,4}(-.*)(\.html)$" {
   ......
}
```

Still no luck... With the quotes, it fails to match the location in both cases. Could someone please help?

Comment: I don’t know nginx, but I do know a bit about regular expressions. Are you sure you need the backslash before the dash?  Normally dash isn’t special except inside brackets.

Comment: @Scott well, not really :) I thought I have to escape it. Just tried it in regex tester and verified, that it is not needed. Thank you for the hint

Comment: `/` doesn't need to be escaped. Have a try with: `location ~* /[0-9]{1,4}(-.*\.html)$ {`

Comment: @Toto thank you. I need to match numbers only immediatelly after a slash, that is why I ecaped it. Anyway, I tried your suggestion, but the behavior unfortunatelly remains the same

Comment: `nginx` will not have restarted in your first attempt (without quotes) - it would still be running the previous configuration. The second attempt (with quotes, with or without the spurious back-slash) works for me. What happens inside the `location` block?

Comment: @RichardSmith I am testing it on http://nginx.viraptor.info , maybe it is not 100% reliable. Inside the block there will be a rewrite from the URI with the numbers and .html extension, to URI without them. I didn't focus on the rewrites so far. I wanted to have the location problem solved first... As I read about the topic more and more, I am getting suspitious, that this may not be a correct approach in all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I finally used for this particular problem with the location, containing curly braces is to avoid them, and repeat the location block for each possible combination. That means

```
location ~* /[0-9](-.*)(\.html)$ {
```

for .../8-....html

```
location ~* /[0-9][0-9](-.*)(\.html)$ {
```

for .../88-....html

```
location ~* /[0-9][0-9][0-9](-.*)(\.html)$ {
```

for .../888-....html etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify it with `+` which means "at least one of this"

`location ~* /[0-9]+(-.*)(\.html)$ {`